# Hibernate createCriteria on an interface causes N queries rather than 1

Tags: hibernate, criteria

My situation is this:

We have a superclass, "MyAbstractEntity"

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MyTable")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "DISCRIMINATOR", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@DiscriminatorValue("FOO")
public abstract class MyAbstractEntity implements Comparable<MyAbstractEntity> {
```

This class in turn has quite a few subclasses, looking like this:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("BAR")
public class MyEntity extends MyAbstractEntity implements MyInterface {
```

About half of the subclasses implement "MyInterface".

I have a Criteria in which I am interested in getting only objects from a class implementing that interface.
When I define my Criteria like this:

```
Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(MyInterface.class)
```

Hibernate turns around and generates one DB-call for each implementation of the interface and the DB-guys goes nuts. I was half expecting Hibernate to translate this into something that used an "in" clause on the DISCRIMINATOR column rather than creating a separate call for each implementation.

I've tried googling around for this, but unfortunately my results get polluted by the fact that my query contains "hibernate", "criteria" and "interface" and I keep bumping into pages that either explain the API or demonstrates basic examples.

I am aware that I *could* create the Criteria on "MyAbstractEntity" rather than "MyInterface" and remove unwanted results but I want this filtering to happen in the database.

Is there no way to tell Hibernate that I want everything in one single db-call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not get Nizet's solution to work so my slightly dirty way of doing it was:

```
Restrictions.sqlRestriction("{alias}.DISCRIMINATOR in (" + discriminatorValues + ")")
```

where discriminatorValues is a static field initialized in a static block by using a Spring helper class.

```
    Set<Class <? extends MyAbstractEntity>> result = new HashSet<Class <? extends MyAbstractEntity>>();

    ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider provider = new ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider(true);
    provider.addIncludeFilter(new AssignableTypeFilter(MyInterface.class));
    Set<BeanDefinition> components = provider.findCandidateComponents("path/to/package/with/subclasses");
    for (BeanDefinition component : components) {
        Class<?> clazz = null;
        try {
            clazz = Class.forName(component.getBeanClassName());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            ; //stuff some WTF-message into the logger
        }

        result.add((Class<? extends MyAbstractEntity>) clazz);
    }

    String sep = "";
    for (Class<? extends MyAbstractEntity> o : result) {
        discriminatorValues += sep + "'" + o.getAnnotation(DiscriminatorValue.class).value() + "'";
        sep = ",";
    }
```

Not the kind of solution I wanted to go for, but the resulting SQL looks like I wanted it to...
(and new implementations of the interface will be included in the query with no further action from future devs)

Answer (score 1):

You could use an `in` clause on the implicit `class` property:

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.in("myAbstractEntity.class", 
                             new Class[] {MyFirstSubClass.class, MySecondSubClass.class}));
```

I've had bugs with these in the past, where the classes had to be replaced by the discriminator values, but I don't remember exactly when this bug happened and if it has been fixed. So you could have to use

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.in("myAbstractEntity.class", 
                             new String[] {MyFirstSubClass.DISCRIMINATOR_VALUE, MySecondSubClass.DISCRIMINATOR_VALUE}));
```

Comment: But wouldn't I then have to change the restriction any time a new subclass starts implementing the interface? We're sitting in a gigantic code-base which we're about to hand over to maintenance and I am trying to avoid a solution which would require them to somehow know they have to go and update my restrictions every time a new subclass starts implementing the interface. I guess I could combine your solution with some reflection magic to discover which subclasses are to be included runtime but I would prefer if Hibernate could just "handle it" for me.

Comment: That's indeed a problem. I'm not sure there is a magical Hibernate solution, though

Comment: That's what I feared, I might look into some reflection combined with your solution then. Thanks.